# How would I send live video using OpenCV to Tensorflow?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, tensorflow

Basically I have used Teachable Machine, which is a site by Google that allows you to train your own Machine Learning Model. It also has a feature where you can export your code. I have never used Tensorflow or OpenCV/cv2 so this is quite a daunting process for me.

Here is my code:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
# Disable scientific notation for clarity
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
# Load the model
model = tensorflow.keras.models.load_model('keras_model.h5', compile=False)

# Create the array of the right shape to feed into the keras model
# The 'length' or number of images you can put into the array is
# determined by the first position in the shape tuple, in this case 1.
data = np.ndarray(shape=(1, 224, 224, 3), dtype=np.float32)

# Replace this with the path to your image
image = Image.open('Path to your image')

# Make sure to resize all images to 224, 224 otherwise they won't fit in the array
image = image.resize((224, 224))
image_array = np.asarray(image)

# Normalize the image
normalized_image_array = (image_array.astype(np.float32) / 127.0) - 1

# Load the image into the array
data[0] = normalized_image_array

# run the inference
prediction = model.predict(data)
print(prediction)
```

It is straight out of teachable machine. Currently, the program only allows me to upload a single image that the program will classify.

Is it possible to get live video streamed to this program using my program (preferably with openCV.)

Also, if you have time, would it be possible to show me how I could put colored boxes around the classes that the program has identified.

I am sorry if this is too much to ask for!

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of how to do what you are asking in this github issue: https://github.com/googlecreativelab/teachablemachine-community/issues/55#issuecomment-560447633

Hope that works